# Using EF stored procedures, return entity doesn't show foreign key fields

Tags: .net, sql-server, silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

In my Silverlight app, I try to using a SQL Server stored procedures with Entity Framework to get Customer entities.

In Function mapping, I also config to the function that return Entities Customer. As expected, it has properties like `CustomerID`, `CustomerName`, etc.

However, its Foreign Key properties are missing. I cannot see any ID on the entities returned. For instance, Customer has a foreign key `EmployeeRangeID` which reference to EmployeeRange table.

If I use LINQ 2 EF, I can see EmployeeRangeID on Customer entity returned. When I use SP IN EF to return Customer entites, I cannot see EmployeeRangeID on EmployeeRangeReference or EmployeeRangeID on the Client.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Using SQL Server, correct? Edit your question to include your stored procedure.

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQL Sever. I'm so sorry, I can't post my SP because of legal of my company. And my SP is very simple. It's just select * From Customer. Plz help me!

Comment: I'm not asking to post your exact stored proc, but something to help us reproduce your issue. Can you make another test/example stored proc on your system to demonstrate your problem?

Answer (score 0):

How are you mapping this?  When you setup the Function Import to return the Customer entity that's generated in your model, it's no different than that entity used elsewhere.  So there may be an issue in your mapping and it's generating a new entity type...